# Is this an approximation of a cosine?

Tags: trigonometry

I have encountered this math :

$$x = \sqrt{1 - r^2 / (1 + r^2) }$$

I believe x is the cosine of a cone half angle where the base of the cone is a circle of radius r, but I can't work out how - can anyone shed any light on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. The "height" of the cone is $1$. Thus $x = \cos (\theta/2) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+r^2}}$, and from this the expression above follows.

Comment: of course $x = \sqrt{1-\frac{r^2}{r^2+1}}$ = $\sqrt{\frac{r^2+1}{r^2+1} - \frac{r^2}{r^2+1}}$ = $\sqrt{\frac{r^2+1-r^2}{r^2+1}}$ = $\sqrt{\frac{1+r^2-r^2}{r^2+1}}$ = $\sqrt{\frac{1}{r^2+1}}$ = $\frac{\sqrt{1}}{\sqrt{r^2+1}}$ = $\frac{1}{\sqrt{r^2 + 1}}$ thanks